# Can we overlap compute operation with memory operation without pinned memory on CPU?

Tags: pytorch, cuda, cuda-streams

I`m trying to overlap the computation and memory operation with HuggingFace SwitchTransformer.

Here’s a detailed explanation.

- The memory operation is for data movement from CPU to GPU, and its size is 4MB per block.
- The number of blocks is variable (typically from 2 to 6 in total).
- The computation operation comprises several very small computation operations like GEMM, which takes 10s to 100s microseconds per each.
- I'm trying to use CudaStream, so I created two different Cuda streams and pushed memory operation and computation operation to each of them.
- But it had not been overlapped.

```
            s_0 = torch.cuda.Stream()  # Create a new stream.
            s_1 = torch.cuda.Stream()  # Create a new stream.

            with torch.cuda.stream(s_0):
                this_gate_info = router_mask, router_probs, router_logits
                router_mask = router_mask.bool()
                idx_mask = router_mask.transpose(1,2)
                idx_mask = torch.cat(torch.split(idx_mask, 1, dim=0), dim=2)
                idx_mask = idx_mask.sum(dim=2)
                idx_mask = idx_mask.squeeze()
                    
                if next_blk is not None:
                    active_idx = torch.nonzero(idx_mask, as_tuple=True)
                    for idx in active_idx[0]:
                        tmp = getattr(next_blk.layer[-1].mlp.experts, "expert_{}".format(idx))
                        tmp.prefetching()    ## THIS IS MEMORY OPERATION COLORED GREEN IN THE FIGURE

            with torch.cuda.stream(s_1):
                delayed_router_mask, delayed_router_probs, delayed_router_logits = delayed_gate_info
                delayed_expert_index = torch.argmax(delayed_router_mask, dim=-1)
                    
                delayed_router_mask = delayed_router_mask.bool()
                delayed_idx_mask = delayed_router_mask.transpose(1,2)
                delayed_idx_mask = torch.cat(torch.split(delayed_idx_mask, 1, dim=0), dim=2)
                delayed_idx_mask = delayed_idx_mask.sum(dim=2)
                delayed_idx_mask = delayed_idx_mask.squeeze()

                for idx, expert in enumerate(self.experts.values()):
                    if delayed_idx_mask[idx] != 0:
                        expert_counter = expert_counter + 1
                        next_states[delayed_router_mask[:, :, idx]] = expert(hidden_states[delayed_router_mask[:, :, idx]], None, None, None)
```

[image]

And here's my question.

1. Firstly, I'd learn that to overlap the memory operation (CPU->GPU) and computation operation, the memory in the CPU should be pinned. But in my case, as can be seen in the figure, it is pageable memory, not pinned. Is it a reason that this cannot be overlapped?
2. Second, I conducted an experiment to prove it with a simple example (overlapping GEMM with CPU->GPU memory operation), and here`s the output.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.cuda.nvtx as nvtx_cuda

torch.cuda.cudart().cudaProfilerStart()

cuda = torch.device('cuda')
nvtx_cuda.range_push("STREAM INIT")
s_0 = torch.cuda.Stream()  # Create a new stream.
s_1 = torch.cuda.Stream()  # Create a new stream.
nvtx_cuda.range_pop()

A = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
B = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
C = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
D = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
E = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
F = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")

a = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), pin_memory=False)
b = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")

iter = 10

for i in range(iter):

    with torch.cuda.stream(s_0):
        nvtx_cuda.range_push("S0")
        C = A.matmul(B)
        F = D.matmul(E)
        nvtx_cuda.range_pop()
        
    with torch.cuda.stream(s_1):
        nvtx_cuda.range_push("S1")
        nvtx_cuda.range_pop()
        b = a.to(cuda)

torch.cuda.cudart().cudaProfilerStop()
```

[image]
This is pageable memory.
[image]
This is pinned memory.

It seems like pageable memory also can be overlapped.
Then, what is the reason that my application is not overlapping?

Comment: In the first picture one can see in the CUDA API row that stream 1 operations are only launched after the transfers are completed. That is why there is no overlap.

Comment: Implicit in this analysis is that all of the pytorch APIs are fully asynchronous on the host and fully analogous to what we assume are the equivalent bare CUDA runtime calls. That may not be the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, for arbitrary sizes and situations, in order to overlap a D->H or H->D copy operation with a kernel execution, its necessary to:

1. use `cudaMemcpyAsync()`
2. use a created stream, not the default stream
3. use a pinned pointer/buffer for the host allocation

The kernel launch in question would also need to be launched into a different, non-null stream.  (Yes, modifying stream default behavior could affect some of this.  I am assuming the default null stream behavior.)

Regarding the last item (3), this is a general statement.  Support for this comes from several places in the documentation, including [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#asynchronous-and-overlapping-transfers-with-computation) and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-runtime).

However, a D->H or H->D copy from a non-pinned buffer [proceeds in stages](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/api-sync-behavior.html#api-sync-behavior).  The CUDA runtime creates its own pinned buffers that are used for all pageable copy operations, and for small enough transfers that fit within the buffers maintained by the CUDA runtime (size is not specified anywhere), the transfer operation may be asynchronous.  In that case, its possible to witness overlap from a pageable buffer.  Since this is not formally specified, and sizes and whatnot necessary for sensible use are unspecified, in practice people typically do not depend on such behavior, and the usual advice is to use pinned memory to achieve overlap.

That doesn't describe your 2nd case, however, where the profiler appears to indicate overlap for a presumably "large" transfer.  However the staged transfer is key to understanding this as well.

When a transfer operation satisfies items 1 and 2 (above), but not 3, and is of large enough size to not fit entirely in the staging buffer, the CUDA runtime will break the transfer operation into pieces that will fit in the staging buffer.  It then transfers the data on the host from your pageable buffer to a pinned buffer.  The pinned buffer contents are then transferred to the device.  This operation is repeated until all data is transferred.  The `cudaMemcpyAsync()` operation itself does not return, i.e. does not unblock the CPU thread, until the final chunk is transferred to the (pinned) staging buffer.

So considering that, if you launch a kernel, and then initiate a pageable transfer (exactly your test case) you may indeed witness transfer activity while the kernel is still executing (ie. overlap).  However, as also indicated in your traces,  the `cudaMemcpyAsync()` operation is not returning (unblocking the CPU thread) until the transfer operation is complete or nearly complete.

And this is a problem.  This behavior (CPU blocking) is disastrous for trying to issue carefully orchestrated concurrent/asynchronous work to the GPU.  So while you may be able to witness some overlap for a carefully constructed test case, in the general case, using pageable buffers makes it quite difficult to launch work that is not intended to take place until sometime in the future. It makes it essentially impossible to issue a large tranche of asynchronous work to the GPU.

As a simple example, your particular test-case pageable transfer is being overlapped because the transfer was issued *after* the kernel launch in question.  The kernel launch is always non-blocking to the CPU thread, so the CPU thread can begin the pageable transfer, thus the overlap.  If we had reversed the order of execution, however, for the most part that particular transfer could not overlap with that particular kernel, because the CPU thread is blocked during the transfer, and cannot proceed to launch the kernel. This appears to be what is happening in your original case:

[image]

(Yes, I understand your test case has a loop, so it may well overlap with some other kernel launch.)

So the general recommendation is to use pinned buffers, when issuing asynchronous work to the GPU where overlap is desired.  Anything else is very difficult to rely on for efficient work execution.

Comment: Cool. I really appreciated it. To give you one more question, just like you said, I think the pinned memory transfer should not call the CudaStreamSynchronous() (Colored in Green in the Nsys), but it seems like it calls it. I believe this is not going to happen for C++ and CUDA. Do you think this is happening because it is PyTorch + CUDA?

I really agree with you that only launching a pageable memory operation after the computation kernel can be overlapped, but pinned memory operation should always be overlapped regardless it is launched after or before the computation kernel.

Comment: But in the example, launching memory before the kernel cannot be overlapped even though its pinned memory, and I'm suspecting it is because of PyTorch CUDA.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that pytorch issues a `cudaStreamSynchronize()` after the `cudaMemcpyAsync()`.